# Pandas reset_index gives TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=float64)' and 'str'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe from which I am deleting empty rows.

After that, I want to get a row index by finding specific string in column and then use that index to split the dataframe.

```
split_index = (df_all[df_all.iloc[:,0]=='Platform'].index.item())
```

However, because multiple rows have been deleted from dataframe, the index is incorrect.

I want to reset the index so the found row has correct index. I have used the following as  I don't want index saved as a column:

```
df_all.reset_index(drop=True)
```

but it doesn't reset index.

I then tried doing:

```
df_all.reset_index(drop=True, inplace = True)
```

which gives this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=float64)' and 'str'
```

How can I reset index to do what I want?

Edit to add:

This is how my dataframe is being created `df_all`:

```
# get all csv files, append to list
file_list = list()
for file in table_files:
    df_file = pd.read_csv(pdf_data_path + file, header=None)
    file_list.append(df_file)

# create new df from file list
df_raw = pd.concat(file_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

# remove trailing spaces entire df 
df_all = df_raw.applymap(lambda x: x.rstrip() if type(x)==str else x)

# exclude top 2 rows
df_all = df_all.iloc[2:]

# drop empty rows
df_all.dropna(how='all', inplace = True)
```

Sample of `df_all`:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
University of Oxford/AstraZeneca,Non-Replicating Viral Vector,ChAdox1-S,1,,IM,,PACTR202006922165132 2020-001072-15 Interim Report,2020-001228-32,ISRCTN89951424 NCT04516746,
CanSino Biological Inc./Beijing Institute of Biotechnology,Non-Replicating Viral Vector,Adenovirus Type 5 Vector,1,,IM,ChiCTR2000030906 Study Report,,ChiCTR2000031781 Study Report,NCT04526990,
Gamaleya Research Institute,Non-Replicating Viral Vector,Adeno-based (rAd26-S+rAd5-S),2,"0,21 days",IM,NCT04436471 NCT04437875,,,NCT04530396,
Sinovac,Inactivated,Inactivated,2,"0, 14 days",IM,,NCTO4383574 NCTO4352608,,NCT04456595 669/UN6.KEP/EC/2020,
Wuhan Institute of Biological Products/Sinopharm,Inactivated,Inactivated,2,"0,14 or 0,21 days",IM,,ChiCTR2000031809 Interim Report,,ChiCTR2000034780,
Beijing Institute of Biological Products/Sinopharm,Inactivated,Inactivated,2,"0,14 or 0,21 days",IM,,ChiCTR2000032459,,ChiCTR2000034780,
Moderna/NIAID,RNA,LNP-encapsulated mRNA,2,"O, 28 days",IM,NCT04283461 Interim Report,,NCT04405076,NCT04470427,
BioNTech/Fosun Pharma/Pfizer,RNA,3 LNP-mRNAs,2,"O, 28 days",IM,,2020-001038-36 ChiCTR2000034825 Study Report,,NCT04368728,
"Anhui Zhifei Longcom Biopharmaceutical/Institute of Microbiology, Chinese Academy of Sciences",Protein Subunit,Adjuvanted recombinant protein (RBD-Dimer),2 or 3,"0,28 or 0,28,56 days",IM,NCT04445194,,NCT04466085,,
Curevac,RNA,mRNA,2,"0, 28 days",IM,NCTO4449276,,NCT04515147,,
"Institute of Medical Biology, Chinese Academy of Medical Sciences",Inactivated,Inactivated,2,"0, 28 days",IM,NCT04412538,NCT04470609,,,
"Research Institute for Biological Safety Problems, Rep of Kazakhstan",Inactivated,Inactivated,2,"O, 21 days",IM,,NCT04530357,,,
Inovio Pharmaceuticals/ International Vaccine Institute,DNA,DNA plasmid vaccine with electroporation,2,"0, 28 days",ID,,NCT04447781 NCTO4336410,,,
Osaka University/ AnGes/ Takara Bio,DNA,DNA plasmid vaccine + Adjuvant,2,"0, 14 days",IM,,NCT04463472 NCT04527081,,,
Cadila Healthcare Limited,DNA,DNA plasmid vaccine,3,"0, 28, 56 days",ID,,CTRI/2020/07/026352,,,
Genexine Consortium,DNA,DNA Vaccine (GX-19),2,"0, 28 days",IM,,NCT04445389,,,
Bharat Biotech,Inactivated,Whole-Virion Inactivated,2,"0, 14 days",IM,,NCT04471519,,,
Janssen Pharmaceutical Companies,Non-Replicating Viral Vector,Ad26COVS1,2,"O, 56 days",IM,,NCT04436276,,NCT04505722 (not yet recruiting),
Novavax,Protein Subunit,Full length recombinant SARS CoV-2 glycoprotein nanoparticle vaccine adjuvanted with Matrix M,2,"0, 21 days",IM,,NCT04368988,,,
"Kentucky Bioprocessing, Inc",Protein Subunit,RBD-based,2,"O, 21 days",IM,,NCT04473690,,,
Arcturus/Duke-NUS,RNA,mRNA,,,IM,,NCTO4480957,,,
ReiThera/LEUKOCARE/Univercells,Non-Replicating Viral Vector,Replication defective Simian Adenovirus (GRAd) encoding S,1,,IM,NCT04528641,,,,
Clover Biopharmaceuticals Inc./GSK/Dynavax,Protein Subunit,Native like Trimeric subunit Spike Protein vaccine,2,"O, 21 days",IM,NCT04405908,,,,
Vaxine Pty Ltd/Medytox,Protein Subunit,Recombinant spike protein with AdvaxM adjuvant,1,,IM,NCT04453852,,,,
University of Queensland/CSL/Seqirus,Protein Subunit,Molecular clamp stabilized Spike protein with MF59 adjuvant,2,"o, 28 days",IM,ACTRN12620000674932p,,,,
Medigen Vaccine Biologics Corporation/NIAID/Dynavax,Protein Subunit,S-2P protein + CpG 1018,2,"o, 28 days",IM,NCT04487210,,,,
"Instituto Finlay de Vacunas, Cuba",Protein Subunit,RBD + Adjuvant,2,"o, 28 days",IM,IFV/COR/04,,,,
"FBRI SRC VB VECTOR, Rospotrebnadzor, Koltsovo",Protein Subunit,Peptide,2,"o, 21 days",IM,NCT04527575,,,,
"West China Hospital, Sichuan University",Protein Subunit,RBD (baculovirus production expressed in Sf9 cells),2,"O, 28 days",IM,ChiCTR2000037518,,,,
Institute Pasteur/Themis/Univ. of Pittsburg CVR/Merck Sharp & Dohme,Replicating Viral Vector,Measles-vector based,1 or 2,"O, 28 days",IM,NCT04497298,,,,
```

### Files can be loaded from GitHub:

```py
df_all = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, header=None) for file in files])

files = ['https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sitrucp/who_vaccine_landscape/master/pdf_data/table-1.csv',
         'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sitrucp/who_vaccine_landscape/master/pdf_data/table-2.csv',
         'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sitrucp/who_vaccine_landscape/master/pdf_data/table-3.csv',
         'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sitrucp/who_vaccine_landscape/master/pdf_data/table-4.csv',
         'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sitrucp/who_vaccine_landscape/master/pdf_data/table-5.csv',
         'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sitrucp/who_vaccine_landscape/master/pdf_data/table-6.csv',
         'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sitrucp/who_vaccine_landscape/master/pdf_data/table-7.csv',
         'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sitrucp/who_vaccine_landscape/master/pdf_data/table-8.csv',
         'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sitrucp/who_vaccine_landscape/master/pdf_data/table-9.csv']
```

Comment: and the full traceback?

Comment: thx, updated. (often these are generic issues so didn't initially provide such detailed info). csv files are in this [Github repository](https://github.com/sitrucp/who_vaccine_landscape)

Comment: Makes sense .. sorry  didn't look at error closely enough, error root line is another downstream operation replacing values from dict, where key is a number which I have set as string. Once I remove quotes from number then it works as expected. But interesting that appears using `df_all.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` prompts this.

Comment: So issue resolved?

Comment: yes resolved, thanks!